# Verifying digital signature on PDF

Tags: pdf

What is the best way to verify digital signature on downloaded PDF files? I am using 19.04.

Comment: It seems that Okular works fine.

Answer (score 3):

As of now, the best solution I found is the Adobe Reader DC snap, which uses wine:
https://snapcraft.io/acrordrdc . Only, take care of *not* disconnecting the network for this snap, as the installer suggests doing to avoid updates (possibly not working), because this obviously prevents signature verification.

I have been trying the "native" [Adobe Reader 9](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux), [Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/) and [PDF Studio Viewer](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/) but I found them incomplete. Adobe Reader 9 apparently has an outdated verification method, Master PDF Editor appears to verify the signature but still shows a "?" rather than a "Valid signature" mark in my PDF, and PDF Studio Viewer marks the (supposedly valid) signature as Invalid because of not supporting the signature handler (Adobe.PPKLite::ETSI.RFC3161).

This is based on PDFs from only one authority, but for non-experts in digital signatures and certification methods, it appears that the snap is the best option if one only wants to verify a signature and go on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to open a .PDF in LibreOffice. If PDF is signed, it shows a message and one can check the signatures by clicking "Show Signatures".

---

Example: to **verify signature metadata**, at LibreOffice 7+ Draw. It shows a bar when we open the document:
[image]
click at "Show Signatures" and "View Certificate details...".

[image]

PS: **to validate the signature**, see https://superuser.com/a/1163219

Answer (score 1):

I am using procertumSmartsign app that verifies signatures compliant with European eIDAS standard in PDF, XML (both internal and external signatures) and any other files (external signatures):

https://www.support.certum.eu/en/cert-offer-smart-sign/

[image]

Please note that European eSignature hierarchy is different than in other parts of the word.